# FSharpChart: two scales on same graphic

Tags: f#, fsharpchart

I'm using FSharpChart to print on the same graphic the moving average and the volume of a stock. The problem is that one graphic goes from 20 to 50 more or less, the other from 0 to 80 mln, so when I combine the two, one is split to the bottom and this is useless. Can I have two different scales on the Y-axis so that the two graphic "merge" correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this if you set the `AxisType` of one of the series to `AxisType.Secondary`.  Of course it's then up to you to make sure axis labels, legend, etc make it clear which data maps to which scale.

```
open FSharp.Charting
open System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

let squaresChart = [ 1 .. 100 ] |> List.map (fun n -> (n, n*n)) |> Chart.Line
let cubesChart   = [ 1 .. 100 ] |> List.map (fun n -> (n, n*n*n)) |> Chart.Line

let bad = 
    [ squaresChart 
      cubesChart ]
    |> Chart.Combine

let good = 
    [ squaresChart
      cubesChart |> Chart.WithSeries.AxisType(YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary) ]
    |> Chart.Combine
```

Bad:

[image]

Good:

[image]

This works, but in the quick testing I've done to write this answer, it appears that FSharp.Charting has some bugs whereby certain customizations are "infectious."  After creating the "good" chart, the secondary axis now appears even when I don't want it:

```
// secondary axis sticks around
bad |> Chart.WithTitle(Text = "Why secondary axis?")

// now the title and the secondary axis *both* stick around!
Chart.Rows [bad; good]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've opened a bug for this odd behavior: https://github.com/fslaborg/FSharp.Charting/issues/82

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you cannot `Chart.Combine` charts with independent scales. However, you may stack them on each other with a different combinator, for example with `Chart.Rows` like in snippet below

```
#I @"C:\code\packages\FSharp.Charting.0.90.12"
#load "FSharp.Charting.fsx"

open FSharp.Charting
open System

let parabola = [ for x in 1.0 .. 1.0 .. 10.0 -> (x, (x ** 2.0) * 1000.0 ) ]
let curve = [ for i in 0.0 .. 0.02 .. 2.0 * Math.PI -> (sin i, cos i * sin i) ] 

Chart.Rows([Chart.Line(parabola); Chart.Line(curve)])
```

producing the combined chart with constituents having quite different scale:

[image]